# Quadratic Gaussian with complex linear coefficient

Tags: complex-numbers, gaussian-integral

A quick question about Gaussians.

Normally Gaussians with quadratic terms are defined as

$\int dx e^{-ax^{2} + bx} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^{2}}{4a}}$.

However, what happens if $b$ can be complex valued? More precisely, can the equation be modified as 
$\int dx e^{-ax^{2} + bx} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{\bar{b}b}{4a}}$?

Kind regards,
Livius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does the $\frac {b^2}{4a}$ factor come from?

$-ax^2 + bx = -a(x-\frac {b}{2a})^2 + \frac {b^2}{4a}$

Does a complex $b$ change the numerator of the $\frac {b^2}{4a}$ term to $\frac {|b|^2}{4a}$ ?

Comment: Got it, thank you.